# Solr: Error while creating remote solr core

Tags: indexing, solr, upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

After upgrading solr from 4.7 to 5.3 I get the following errors when queries are executed during restart of one of the nodes (2 solr nodes, master/slave):

```
 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'master_Reseller': Could not create a new core in /hybris/configs/solr/server/solr/./cores/master_Reseller/as another core is already defined there
 at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:662)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:214)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:194)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:675)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:443)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:210)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179) org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'master_Reseller': Could not create a new core in /hybris/configs/solr/server/solr/./cores/master_Reseller/as another core is already defined there
 at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:662)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:214)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:194)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:675)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:443)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:210)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
```

What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Regards

Andy

Comment: have you tried just deleting the folders on the disk and the recreating the index via a full index?

Comment: I tried. But on the next restart I get the same error message. The question is why is solr trying to create a new core?

Comment: Hm, maybe you can try recreating the solr config from scratch with the one provided by hybris?